# How to show/hide dynamically added span item onclick with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to display an array of items like this:

```
[...] /* onClick --> */ [1, 2, 3]
```

```
[1, 2, 3] /* onClick --> */ [...]
```

My problem is this that I am adding this array dynamically, so I can't have a variable like `isHidden` in the code itself.

I am adding the array like this:

```js
let arr_shown = `<span class="toggle">[${myArrayString}]</span>`;
let arr_hidden = `<span class="toggle">[...]</span>`;
```

and in the html:

```html
<span v-html="arr_shown"></span> <!-- or arr_hidden -->
```

I am using `vuejs2` for my project.
How to be able to toggle between `arr_shown` and `arr_hidden` on click?

### Edit

I have a `prop` like this:

```
props: ['arrays']
```

I have a `computed` value like this:

```
convertedArrays() {
    let data = []
    for (let array of this.arrays) {
        data.push(`<span class="toggle">[${array.join()}]</span>`)
    }
    return data;
}
```

And I am using in the html like this:

```
<tr v-for="item in convertedArrays">
<td><span v-html="item"></span></td>
</tr>
```

### Update

what if I have array of different objects passed to the `prop` `arrays` , example:

```
:arrays="[1, 2, [1, 2, 3], 3]"
```

I do not want to do anything to the numbers but apply the solution to the arrays. Example output:

```
1
2
[...] /*or*/ [1, 2, 3]
3
```

How to do this?

Should I do something like this to make aware the component to which I am passing the prop of the item type:

```
:arrays="[1, 2, {type: 'array', value: [1, 2, 3]}, 3]"
```

and in the component:

```
for (let item of this.arrays) {
    if (!!item.type) {
        /* array */
    } else {
         /* number */
    }
}
```

Comment: _"My problem is this that I am adding this array dynamically, so I can't have a variable like `isHidden` in the code itself."_  could you please elaborate on this as it doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: I have a list of such arrays added dynamically, so I dont know their number and thus i can't use a variable

Comment: Sorry, that's still not very clear. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58159955/edit) and explain with an example?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to more closely match your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you have data coming in that is an array of numbers or arrays and you want to be able to individually toggle each array.

To do so, you'll need to maintain a *visibility* state for each entry.

This can be done using a plain object that looks like this...

```js
{
  "0": true,
  "1": false,
  // etc
}
```

Where the keys are array indices and the values the visibility state.

This object can be kept in sync with the prop data by using a [*watcher*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

You can then use this to control how your data is rendered by creating a computed property that formats the array values.

```js
Vue.component('ArrayTable', {
  template: `<table border="1">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in formattedArray">
      <td>
        <span v-if="item.isToggleable" @click="toggle(index)" class="toggle">
          [{{ toggles[index] ? item.data : '...' }}]
        </span>
        <span v-else>{{ item.data }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>`,
  props: ['arrays'],
  data: () => ({ toggles: {} }),
  computed: {
    formattedArray () {
      return this.arrays.map((data, index) => {
        let isArray = Array.isArray(data)
        return {
          isToggleable: isArray,
          data: isArray ? data.join(', ') : data
        }
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle (index) {
      this.toggles[index] = !this.toggles[index]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    arrays: {
      immediate: true,
      handler (arrays) {
        // watch for changes to the "arrays" prop and initialise the filter
        this.toggles = arrays.reduce((obj, _, index) =>
          (obj[index] = false, obj), {})
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ myArrays: [] }),
  created () {
    // simulate dynamic loading
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myArrays = [
        1,
        2,
        [1, 2, 3],
        3
      ]
    }, 500)
  }
})
```

```css
.toggle { cursor: pointer; }
table { min-width: 8rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <array-table :arrays="myArrays"></array-table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but I came across another problem, what if the `prop` `arrays` contains some numbers and some arrays, for example `:arrays="[1, [1, 2, 3], 5]"`, I want to implement your solution for arrays, but show the numbers as they are. What to edit in your solution?

Comment: I'd convert them to arrays if they aren't already. I've update my answer

Comment: Actually, I want nothing to be done to the numbers, I only want toggle behavior with arrays, so eventually I don't think they should be converted to arrays.

Comment: This requirement differs wildly to what's in your question. Could you please update the post